# How to login a web site for take the pages tables with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I created a python code, using the pandas library for to take tables from web site, however appear to me a "forbidden error", I think that is why I need to login before to the take the tables from there.

my code in python is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('https://exames.genera.com.br/busca-parentes')
df
```

The error:
[image: error]

Someone can help me to login in this web site in my program?